# Bootstrap custom carousel with responsive thumbnail images IE 11 and Windows Phone 8 browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I am having trouble creating a custom carousel with responsive thumbnail images with the latest version of bootstrap that properly displays with responsive behavior in IE 11 and the latest of the Windows Phone 8 browser; everything seems to be working correctly in IE10 and below in addition to chrome. The problem is that in IE11 and Windows Phone browser the images are not responsive and when screen width is manually reduced the thumbnail images maintain original desktop size and extend beyond the width of the viewport.

I have similar thumbnail image code elsewhere that is not within a carousel and that is responsive and seems to work perfectly. It must be something with my custom carousel code.

This is my compass/sass/css:

```
.carousel-inner .item {
    text-align: center !important;
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
    .carousel-control.left {
        left: 0;
    }
    .carousel-control.right {
        right: 0;
    }
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
    @include transition(opacity 0.5s ease-in-out);
    opacity: 0;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.right {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .next,
.carousel.carousel-fade .prev {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="carousel-index" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/tile1.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1 class="page-header">Header1</h1>
                <p>Content1</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Link1</li>
                    <li>Link2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/tile2.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1 class="page-header">Header2</h1>
                <p>Content2</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Link3</li>
                    <li>Link4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is within a jumbotron because it is in a header and I want the jumbotron effect. Not sure if that may have something to do with it. It looks perfect on desktop but mobile is shot. Thanks in advance!